# how to "make" 2 circles and "draw" line between them ? with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the user able to make circle when he clicks on the mouse "onClick" and draw a straight line between them with jQuery?

im doing the Dijkstra shortest path algorithm visualization so i need to draw circles as "Nodes" and straight lines as "Path" .. so i need the simplest method to make that please.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show as what you tried so far.

Comment: Make two circles how? In a canvas? With WebGL? With divs? Explain a bit more, please.

Comment: How do you draw a line with jQuery? Do you even know what jQuery is?

Comment: Greetings Omar and welcome to Stackoverflow. You are invited to take the tour of Stackoverflow help center. http://stackoverflow.com/tour You will find usefull information about what can/cannot be ask on this site and also, how to ask for it.

Comment: Guys im not that noob !!, my project is to make visualize the shortest path algorithm, so i need to allow user drawing circles as "nodes" and straight lines as "path"

Comment: and i need THE SIMPLEST WAY TO DO IT .. cuz i need it quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Canvas to draw different objects. You can follow instructions in the tutorial found here – http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/ .

It explains the main and basic bits about drawing circles, lines, everything you need. This is the easiest way to draw in HTML + JS. You don't need jQuery in this case at all (maybe just to find the canvas element on page).

Comment: Yes, it answers how to draw cirles, but I think that's the least of the topic starter's problem.

Comment: I think that is his main goal, to be honest :-) . It will point him in the right direction.

Comment: but i need to use them later, to calculate the length of the lines he draw .. so this will be enough ? and if so is there any code of doing that or something similar ?

Comment: You can calculate all the values you need – if you read the code on the tutorial page carefully, you will see which instructions perform which action. To lines - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: Thanks a lot, so this i need to do a visualization for shortest path algorithm, or even the first step ? 
and sorry for your time :)

Comment: Yes, yes, this is the simplest way you can do that in HTML + JS, just draw the circles and lines where you need them. No worries about my time ;-)

Comment: i study most of it, but i cant find something telling me how to make circle "onClick" .. i want to create a small circle as "Node" when user click, and create a line representing a path between two circles he made the same way, thanks in advance